# How to add JWT authentication with passport-steam

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

Simple JWT authenticated mern app ([here](https://github.com/kmccullen97/mern-auth)) in place using redux and create-react-app. I want to add [passport-steam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-steam) as an authentication method, however I'm not sure how to handle adding a JWT to the passport-steam strategy. Below is what I have:

```js
// Steam
router.get('/steam', passport.authenticate('steam', { session: false }));

router.get(
  '/steam/return',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const user = req.user
    jwt.sign(
      { id: user.id },
      'JWT_secret',
      { expiresIn: '2h' },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({
          user: user,
          token,
        });
      }
    );
    res.redirect('/')
  }
)
```

Using the default steam strategy It works and user data is added to the DB, but there's no token in local storage. I'm not sure how to do it with steam as I'm not dispatching an action/not sure If I can. Do I need to authenticate via steam, grab and save the data to the database and then dispatch another action to retrieve it and add the JWT, or is there a better method?

Comment: Passport can't help you save the token to the browsers local storage, that is something that has to be done in your client code. When your server responds to the auth call with the token, in your client, you are supposed to grab the token from the response and set it in the browser local storage with [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Comment: @OTZ I understand that, my questions is - because it's an external link users visit and the return url is a different url (root url) do I need to dispatch a secondary action in the root of the FE app to retrieve the token and user information? or can it be done in the one component (login screen)?

Comment: Ok, not I get. So you need a way to get the auth token to the user after successful OAuth operation redirects them to the home page. What I think you can do is add the authToken as a query params in your redirect response, something like this: `res.redirect('/?authToken=<jwt-token>')` and then have a check in the component associated with the home(`/`) page such that if the authToken is present as a query param, it dispatch some sort of action to acknowledge that a user is logged in. I hope that makes sense.